# Unused ListBoxItem causing binding errors if content is not null

Tags: c#, wpf

I have noticed this strange thing with ListBoxItem, even if you don't actually do anything with the ListBoxItem you created it will cause 2 binding errors if it's content is not null. Note that I do not create any bindings, and I have posted all the code you need to reproduce those errors.

```
ListBoxItem li = new ListBoxItem();
```

or

```
ListBox lb = new ListBox();
ListBoxItem li = new ListBoxItem();
li.Content = "Something";
lb.Items.Add(li);
```

Won't cause any errors, but

```
ListBoxItem li = new ListBoxItem();
li.Content = "Something";
```

Results in this:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=HorizontalContentAlignment; DataItem=null; target element is 'ListBoxItem' (Name=''); target property is 'HorizontalContentAlignment' (type 'HorizontalAlignment')
>
> System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=VerticalContentAlignment; DataItem=null; target element is 'ListBoxItem' (Name=''); target property is 'VerticalContentAlignment' (type 'VerticalAlignment')

Could anyone tell what causes this behavior?

Comment: Where is the XAML for your binding?

Comment: No xaml and no bindings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because the default style for `ListBoxItem` contains a `Binding` with `RelativeSource` to get the `Horizontal/Vertical` `ContentAlignment` of the containing `ItemsControl` for the `ListBoxItem`'s alignments.

Something like this:

```
<Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="{Binding HorizontalContentAlignment RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl}}"/>
</Style>
```

You are creating a `ListBoxItem` that is not contained in an `ItemsControl`, so the `RelativeSource` `Binding` fails to find an ancestor of that type.

Comment: Well it's actually not the same scenario. First of all you are missing content and and it should not be added to anything which is impossible to do with xaml.

Comment: I misunderstood the question. I'll take another look

Comment: But why does it work if I don't add content? And why do i get error if I don't add it to anything? Shouldn't garbage collector just delete it?

Comment: When you don't set the Content property then the ControlTemplate is not applied and so the binding is not created and does not attempt to resolve the value. When you create an instance of a control WPF will apply the template even if you haven't yet attached it to the visual tree.

Comment: Yes but the error doesn't occur instantly after you set the content since you still can add it to ListBox and you won't get any errors.

Comment: That would be because the template for the ListBoxItem has not yet been rendered until after you add it to the ListBox. Each statement in your method is not executed immediately, the work is added to a queue by the Dispatcher.

Comment: I had the same error with `TreeViewItem`s added to a `List<TreeViewItem>` in the view-model. Later the list was the source of a binding on `TreeView.Items`. Your answer helped me to understand the cause of this warning (well it should be a warning, not an error).